# Selenium server : error timeout chromedriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had a problem for a few days on selenium, when I launch a small number of sessions (5-10) everything works fine but when I start to exceed this number, I get a chrome timeout error message: "chrome timeout" and the browser opens but does not launch the URL and does not close.

I searched the Internet for a solution to this kind of problem, I tried to solve it with what I found but nothing could help, I can't do it. I put the same version for the chromium and the chromium driver (version 81), my Jdk is up to date, I have the latest version of selenium (3.141, but I also tried with selenium 2.48), I tried directly the chromium driver and I did the tests locally, I changed the version of the chromium and the chromium driver, I tried with another driver (opera) but still not ...

Comment: are you using testNG to run test ? how u r running tests ?

Comment: I don't understand the question very well, my code is developed in php with selenium which sends information to the selenium server

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are closing all the instances of the chrome driver(Verify Tear down). This also happens when you create multiple instances.

Comment: yes I always close the chrome driver instance at the end with the quit() function